FindRoot[NDSolve...]
I have a function OdvodNaPolu: $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, and I want to find its zero. The function contains NDSolve and based on the error message it looks like NDSolve does not receive r0 as a number. How can I fix it? Here's the code:
OdvodNaPolu[γ_,ω_,σ_,λ_,r0_]:=(
    sol=NDSolve[{
        (r[θ] (-4 σ ω^2 Cos[θ]^3 r[θ]^5+6 γ Cos[θ]r[θ] r'[θ]^2+2 γ Sin[θ] r'[θ]^3+r[θ]^3 (4 γ Cos[θ]-5 σ ω^2 Cos[θ]^3 r'[θ]^2)+σ ω^2 Cos[θ]^2 r[θ]^4 (-3 Sin[θ] r'[θ]+Cos[θ] r''[θ])+r[θ]^2 (2 γ Sin[θ] r'[θ]-3 σ ω^2 Cos[θ]^2 Sin[θ] r'[θ]^3-2 γ Cos[θ] r''[θ])))/(r[θ]^2+r'[θ]^2)^(3/2)==2 λ Cos[θ] r[θ]^2, 
        r[Pi/2]==r0, 
        r'[Pi/2]==0 
    }, r[θ], {θ, .001, π-.001}];
    SolInterp=(r[θ]/.sol[[1,1]]);
    {θmin,θmax}=(SolInterp/.θ->"Domain")[[1]];
    D[SolInterp,θ]/.θ->θmax
);

{γ,ω,σ,λ}={.06,5,.5,10};
FindRoot[OdvodNaPolu[γ,ω,σ,λ,r0],{r0,.01}]


This is a very common problem newcomers face. You have to prevent FindRoo to do any symbolic analysis of your function. Usually, you do this with _?NumericQ. First, do Clear[OdvodNaPolu], then redefine your function as OdvodNaPolu[γ_, ω_, σ_, λ_, r0_?NumericQ]. For more examples and explanations, please see Common Pitfalls:
User-defined functions, numerical approximation, and NumericQ

Thanks, this solved the problem. I remember i've seen ?NumericQ before somewhere. I'll deffinitely  use this a lot instead of other workarounds for many things.
